# Adding a new position at the end of the file Shell or Perl

Tags: shell, perl

My question is how to add a new position at the end of the file in Shell or Perl?

I have two files:
File A with 536382 lines and the key is third column:

```
abc1111,1070X00Y0,**9999**,B
abc2222,1070X00Y0,**9999**,B
abc3333,1070x00Y0,**9999**,B
```

File B with 946 lines and the key is the first column:

```
**9999**,Position,West
**9998**,Position,West
**9997**,Position,South
**1111**,Position,South
**9999**,Time,Morning
**9997**,Time,Afternoon
```

I want a combination of these two files:

```
abc1111,1070X00Y0,9999,B,West,Morning
abc2222,1070X00Y0,9999,B,West,Morning
abc3333,1070x00Y0,9999,B,West,Morning
```

I was trying shell script but I was receiving a message of out of memory.
So I open for suggestions.

Thank you, so far.

Comment: how big is File B?

Comment: around 1000 lines

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get the results you want by making a few changes to your code.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

open IN2, '<', \<<EOF;
**9999**,Position,West
**9998**,Position,West
**9997**,Position,South
**1111**,Position,South
**9999**,Time,Morning
**9997**,Time,Afternoon
EOF

my %hash;

while ( <IN2> ) {
     chomp;
     my @col2 = split ","; 
     $hash{$col2[0]}{$col2[1]} = $col2[2]; 
} 

open IN1, '<', \<<EOF;
abc1111,1070X00Y0,**9999**,B
abc2222,1070X00Y0,**9999**,B
abc3333,1070x00Y0,**9999**,B
EOF

while ( <IN1> ) { 
    chomp;
    my $key = (split /,/)[2];
    if ( exists( $hash{$key} ) ) { 
        print join(",", $_, @{ $hash{$key} }{ qw/Position Time/ }), "\n";
    }
}
```

This produced output of:

```
abc1111,1070X00Y0,**9999**,B,West,Morning
abc2222,1070X00Y0,**9999**,B,West,Morning
abc3333,1070x00Y0,**9999**,B,West,Morning
```

The changes to the code were

1. `$hash{$col2[0]}{$col2[1]} = $col2[2];` Create a Hash of Hash to hold the `Position` and `Time` keys. They are used in a hash slice here
2. `@{ $hash{$key} }{ qw/Position Time/ })`

Comment: It's worked. Thank you so much. I have a lot to learn. Do you recommend any site?

Answer (score 0):

1. Convert small file into perl's hash
2. Process big file line by line

Comment: I have already did but it stops in this value West and doesn't process the second loop Morning.
while ( <IN2> ) {
    chomp;
    my @ col2 = split ",";
    $hash{$col2[0]} = $col2[2];
}


while ( <IN1> ) {
    chomp;
    my @ col1 = split ",";

    if ( exists( $hash{$col1[2]} ) ) {
        print OUT $col1[2] . "," . $col1[1] . "," . $col1[0] . "," . $col1[3] . "," . $hash{$col1[2]} . "\n";
        }
}